# calling a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a jQuery plugin that is more of a utility class (it doesn't operate on DOM), when I call it, I have to call $.fn.myplugin() instead $.myPlugin() or I have to specify a selector like $('body').myPlugin()?

1. Is there a way to be able to call my plugin just with $.myPlugin() (like $.ajax() and so on)?
2. Am I using plugins to solve the wrong type of problem and I should simply use a javascript object and call it object.myFunction()? (my only reason not to do that is that I like jQuery syntax)

Comment: to have the described behavior, when authoring your plugin, you should do jQuery.myPlugin = ...... instead of $.fn.myPlugin = .....

not that it is a good idea .. but this is the way to do it anyhow

Answer (score 0):

u must use

```
$.fn.myplugin()
```

for more information read [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/why-create-a-jquery-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

you must write your plugin first.

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here
  };
})( jQuery );
```

you can use this plugin by `$('your-selected-dom-element').myPlugin()`.

[this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) might help you.